# Completely remove Backbone view from memory

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a very simple backbone dialog which simply shows a bootstap modal with a message. Im using it throughout the app and have built it so that you pass the title and message to be displayed, and the callback to be executed on click of the button. I have an errorListener and in there the view is created, attached to DOM and rendered:

```
    var messageDialog;

    var callback = function() {
            ....    
            messageDialog.remove();
            messageDialog.unbind();

    };

    ....

    var errorListener = function() {

            if (!messageDialog) {
                messageDialog = new MessageDialog({
                    title: 'Error',
                    message: 'We have encountered an error. Please try again.',
                    buttonText: 'Try Again'
                });
                $('body').append(messageDialog.$el);
                messageDialog.render();
            }

            messageDialog.setCallback(tryAgain);
            messageDialog.show();
    }
```

The problem is after the first time the `messageDialog` is created, attached to the DOM and shown, it wont be shown again. This is because if i do a `console.log()` on `messageDialog`, I stil see it's a varaible containing a Backbone view. I thought after calling `remove()` and `unbind()` in the callback, the `messageDialog` variable would be garbage collected. Do I need to do:

```
messageDialog = null;
```

after the `unbind()`? Is this the correct way of doing things?

Comment: check this https://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/15/zombies-run-managing-page-transitions-in-backbone-apps/

Answer (score 0):

I think that .remove() is enough, it removes it from the DOM and also removes binded events to avoid phantom views.

http://backbonejs.org/#View-remove

Is there any reason that myview.remove(); doesn't feet your needs ?

Hope it helps.